# Does anyone know why the request.get() function may not work

Tags: python

Does anyone know why the following code doesn't work?

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https//yandex.ru')
print(x.status_code)
```

Comment: The website might be blocking it. It is better to use the api in the website

Comment: What is the status code you are seeing? Can you include the response and response headers?

Comment: I am not sure what error you are getting, but your url is not correct. It should be ```'https://yandex.ru'``` instead of ```'https//yandex.ru'```. You forgot the colon.

Comment: You need to provide User-Agent!

Answer (score 0):

This block of code should work:

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://yandex.ru')
print(x.status_code)
```

The issue which you are facing basically means you are not supplying https: or http: in your request URL.

> Invalid URL 'https//yandex.ru': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant
> http://https//yandex.ru?